# How can I get emacs to indent html chunks between php control constructs?

Tags: php, html, emacs, mode, indentation

I have tried every php/html mode (including nxHTML) I can find, but can't find a mode that indents the way I want. Here is an example of what my files contain:

```
<?php if (a == 5): ?>
<span>test</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want emacs to indent the code treating the if/endif as an element, like so:

```
<?php if (a == 5): ?>
  <span>test</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The same goes for for loops and other constructs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've written the major mode web-mode.el (available on http://web-mode.org). This mode is designed for HTML templates that include CSS/JS/PHP/JSP. It indents et synthaxcolors according to the type the block. HTML indentation is quite robust (indentation of tags and attributes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried your mode, and it seems to be on the right track but still doesn't keep enough information to know when you're nested inside a PHP control structure. For example, a PHP if statement nested (but not in the same php chunk) inside of a foreach loop will not indent, it assumes the if statement is not inside anything.

Comment: @user1628932 Could you send me an example (indented the way you want) ? (my email is at the end off http://web-mode.org)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to roll your own.   If all you want to do is make sure blocks like `<?php if ....: ?>` start indenting, and `<?php endif; ?>` stop that level of indent,   depending on your elisp skills, it might not be all that hard.  You might even be able to build a new mode that derives from nxml mode, and tinker with the indentation that way.

For what it's worth, trying to make it work in nxHTML is likely to be a complete disaster.  mostly because you'd be trying to indent across the mode boundaries.

The good news is that you can probably use regexp to handle all of PHPs goofy alternative syntax. The bad news is... PHPs goofy alternative syntax!